# i am creating a function for jet engine to display QR in the post

Tags: php, wordpress, function, jet-engine

I want to be able to display a Qr code dynamically created with the post url, i'm using jet engine qr module, i saw the code in a video but i'snt working for me
this is the function code that i'm trying:

also i want to add this function using code snippets.

```
add_filer( 'jet-engine/listings/allowed-callbacks', 'add_custom_dynamic_field_callback' );

add_filter( 'jet-engine/listing/dynamic-field/callback-args', 'add_custom_dynamic_field_callbacks_args', 0, 3);

add_action ('jet-engine/listing/dynamic-field/callback-controlls' , 'add_custom_control', 0, 1 );


function add_custom_dynamic_field_callbacks( $callbacks) {
    $callbacks['url_as_qr'] = 'Post URL as Qr-code';
    return $callback;
}

function url_as_qr( $value, $code_size) {
    if ( class_exists( 'Jet_Engine_Module_QR_Code') ) {
        $qr = new Jet_Engine_Module_QR_Code();
        $result = $qr->get_qr_code( $value, $code_size['size'] );
    }
    return $result;
}

function add_custom_dynamic_field_callbacks_args( $result, $callback, $settings) {
    if ($callback === 'url_as_qr') {
        $result = array( get_permalink(), $settings['code_size'] );
    }
    return $result;
}
    
function add_cutom_control( $controls ) {
    
    $controls->add_control(
        'code_size' ,
        array(
            'label' => 'QR_Code_Size',
            'type'  => 'slider',
            'range' => array(
                'px' => array(
                    'nis' => 50,
                    'nax' => 400,
                ),
            ),
            'condition' => array(
                'dynamic_field_filter' => 'yes'
                'filter_callback'      => array( 'url_as_qr'),
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some typos in your code that may cause the issues.

1. In the first line: use `add_filter` instead of `add_filer`
2. Typo in the `add_custom_dynamic_field_callbacks` function: you are returning `$callback` instead of `$callbacks`
3. Typo in the `add_custom_control` function: your code says `add_cutom_control` instead of `add_custom_control`
4. There is a missing comma in the `'condition'` array after 'yes'
5. Typo in the 'range' array: It should be `min` and `max` not `nis` and `nax`
6. Incorrect action hook: In the third line the hook should be `jet-engine/listing/dynamic-field/callback-controlls` (`callback-controlls` instead of `callback-controls`).

The corrected code looks like this:

```php
add_filter( 'jet-engine/listings/allowed-callbacks', 'add_custom_dynamic_field_callbacks' );
add_filter( 'jet-engine/listing/dynamic-field/callback-args', 'add_custom_dynamic_field_callbacks_args', 0, 3 );
add_action( 'jet-engine/listing/dynamic-field/callback-controls', 'add_custom_control', 0, 1 );

function add_custom_dynamic_field_callbacks( $callbacks ) {
    $callbacks['url_as_qr'] = 'Post URL as QR-code';
    return $callbacks;
}

function url_as_qr( $value, $code_size ) {
    if ( class_exists( 'Jet_Engine_Module_QR_Code' ) ) {
        $qr = new Jet_Engine_Module_QR_Code();
        $result = $qr->get_qr_code( $value, $code_size['size'] );
    }
    return $result;
}

function add_custom_dynamic_field_callbacks_args( $result, $callback, $settings ) {
    if ( $callback === 'url_as_qr' ) {
        $result = array( get_permalink(), $settings['code_size'] );
    }
    return $result;
}

function add_custom_control( $controls ) {
    $controls->add_control(
        'code_size',
        array(
            'label' => 'QR_Code_Size',
            'type' => 'slider',
            'range' => array(
                'px' => array(
                    'min' => 50,
                    'max' => 400,
                ),
            ),
            'condition' => array(
                'dynamic_field_filter' => 'yes',
                'filter_callback' => array( 'url_as_qr' ),
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

I did not test this code, maybe you could add some error messages to your question if this solution doesn't solve your problem.